# Align center vertical, dosent work with google font

Tags: html, css

I have been searched how to align center verticaly and I found this answer:
[How do I vertically center text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-vertically-center-text-with-css)

So I try do to it in my website but its not working
The reason that that not working its because I use google font when I cancel it in the inspector that text aligned to the middle,
My text is in table cell and I gave it:

```
vertical-align:middle;
```

I also tried to achive that with `line-height` but same result
the text appear at the top

In jsfiddle its work with google font, example: https://jsfiddle.net/e6732sq8/
But In my web dosent, my web:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qRVJrq (sorry for didnt upload to jsfiddle, there its work fine)

If I wasent clear I mean that gray text in the table

Comment: Why do you think it is not centered properly? I tried setting a larger height on that row and in looks like centered: http://codepen.io/eduard-malakhov/pen/EZbOZw?editors=1100#0

Comment: @EduardMalakhov If you will mark the `td` in the inspector you will see its not aligned

Comment: First on (good work) id divs but the second one (not work) is table. and as Eduard says they are aligned well.

Comment: You inspector docks to right of browser?

Comment: @FarzinKanzi bottom

Comment: I still don't see any problem with either row.

Comment: @EduardMalakhov In whice browser do you surf? check it plz in chrome desktop

Comment: I'm using Chrome desktop version 55.0.2883.87 on WIndows

Comment: @EduardMalakhov look at this picture https://2017-uploaded.fresh.co.il/2017/01/28/27145403.png

Comment: I see, but I can't reproduce that.

Comment: @EduardMalakhov maybe its problem with chrome? I use 56 version , one above you, what do you think?

Comment: I also had this problem in google chrome

Answer (score 0):

Set this:

```
td{
display:flex;
align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem *might* be caused by non-Latin characters in the font.

Try adding this to your @font-face declaration:

```css
@font-face {
    /* latin */
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

If you're self hosting the font, you can also run the source font file (e.g. ttf) through [Font Squirrel's Webfont Generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) and choose Latin-only subsetting which would also have the benefit of a smaller font file.